# Drag map lost in OpenLayers 3 when using hover SelectInteraction with ol.events.condition.mouseMove

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I've adapted the [OpenLayers 3 select features example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/select-features.html?q=select) to get hover effect when the user points a feature (taken from a GeoJSON FeatureList), but I've lost the drag map interaction.

```
// Mouse over
var seleccion = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: ol.events.condition.mouseMove,
  style: function (feature, resolution) {
    // Style Manager handles Style Creation
    return [StyleManager.getStyle(feature, true)];
  }
});

map.addInteraction(
  seleccion
);
```

Is there a way to produce a feature style change on hover  without sacrificing the drag/pan interaction?

You can see the same problem in the linked example when you set the **action type**  to Hover.

There's an [unanswered question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ol3-dev/drag$20hover/ol3-dev/I9UKbvwKnwc/wUg-KGTnOl0J) in openlayers 3 mailing list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you had checked the mailing list already.

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2666) of OpenLayers 3.

To get the "hover" effect, the [vector layer example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/vector-layer.html) could be helpful.